# Is there a way to create my own dataset in tensorflow python neural networks?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to figure out how to train my neural network based off of what I would like to it to do. Currently I am using the mnist.npz dataset, which trains the neural network with recognizing digits. I would I to switch to my own dataset, but cant fiqure out how. I tried different method, but it none of them worked for myself. my training preperation code currently looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def show_min_max(array, i):
  random_image = array[i]
  print(random_image.min(), random_image.max())

def plot_image(array, i, labels):
  plt.imshow(np.squeeze(array[i]))
  plt.title(" Class " + str(labels[i]))
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.show()

img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28  
num_classes = 10 

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz")  #training data
(train_images_backup, train_labels_backup), (test_images_backup, test_labels_backup) = mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz") #untrained backup data

print(train_images.shape) 
print(test_images.shape) 

train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0],  img_rows, img_cols, 1) 
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1) 
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1) 

plot_image(train_images, 1, train_labels)
show_min_max(train_images, 100) 

train_images[3000:]=255-train_images[3000:] 

train_images = train_images.astype('float32') 
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') 

train_images /= 255 
test_images /= 255 

plot_image(train_images, 100, train_labels) 
show_min_max(train_images, 100) 

train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes) 
test_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes)
```

Things I Did:

1. Searched through code of tensorflow and mnist database, and which up words to redirect it to mine, but I need my dataset (a folder) to be a `npz` file.
2. I tried to use the function `image_dataset_from_directory()` but it didn't return what I expected / needed.
3. turned all of my images into npz files, yet that still didn't matter.

those are just 3 of the many things I've tried. It would be amazing if I could get help with either turning my dataset into one `npz` file, or just to just restart from the basics (from the code up above(it is the base code with non of my chnages))

`mnist.load_data()` is loading is a `npz` file which contains 4 data values, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test. I for 1 do not know the significance of each of these items, aswell as the fact that I dont know how to turn my dataset (a folder) into an `npz` file. I was following a tutorial during the making of this so therefore I have the backup variables lol.

this is my data currently, its not very big lol. just waiting until I know I can actually use it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Cvs7ie6232BLI9ZicaUJdyhxUu-JB4kV?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, what issues are you having replacing `mnist.load_data` with your own data? You dont need "backup data" (you never use those variables, anyway)

Comment: What specifically have you tried based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the thing that `mnist.load_data()` is loading is a npz file which contains 4 data values, x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train, x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test. I for 1 do not know the significance of each of these items, aswell as the fact that I dont know how to turn my dataset (a folder) into an npz file. I was following a tutorial during the making of this so therefore I have the backup variables lol.

Comment: @G.Anderson
1. Searched through code of tensorflow and mnist database, and which up words to redirect it to mine, but I need my dataset (a folder) to be a npz file.
2. I tried to use the function `image_dataset_from_directory()' but it didn't return what I expected / needed.
3. turned all of my images into npz files, yet that still didn't matter.

those are just 3 of the many things I've tried. It would be amazing if I could get help with either turning my dataset into one npz file, or just to just restart from the basics (from the code up above(it is the base code with non of my chnages

Comment: To clarify, you are still trying to use images? There are multiple examples shown that [use a directory rather than an npz file](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory#used-in-the-notebooks_1). If not images, then you can [do the same for text](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/text_dataset_from_directory)

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I am! this is my data currently, its not very big lol. just waiting until I know I can actually use it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Cvs7ie6232BLI9ZicaUJdyhxUu-JB4kV?usp=sharing

Comment: Please ask questions only once, you can always edit your own questions.